# How to show popup on highchart column click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have to show table on every column click in highchart. I am able to show alert but instead of alert I want to modal popup.

```js
plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      point: {
        events: {
          click: (e) => {
            $('#myModal').show();
            return `<div id="myModal" class="modal">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                    
                          <div class="modal-header-div">
                            <div class="tableTitle">Rule Violations Details</div>
                    
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <h1>Show table</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                    
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>`
          },
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your code should work. You first show the modal then returns (to what function?) its html? You probably should append the html first, then initiate the modal (I'm not sure which library you're using for the modal) and only then call to `.show()` or something like that..

Comment: Thanks Mosh ,yup I did same things and Now i am getting expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a string from the 'click' event function callback will not do anything. You need to manage the elements manually:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: (e) => {
                        var popupContent = `...`;

                        $('#popup').append(popupContent);
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wued0cyh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.events.click